не открывает сайт в WebView
ПИШЕТ ОШИБКУ: Expecting member declaration
хОТЯ ДЕЛАЮ СТРОГО ПО ИНСТРУКЦИИ:
**    binding.WebViewMy.loadUrl(URL)
   // WebSettings = binding.WebViewMy.get
     binding.WebViewMy.settings.javaScriptEnabled;
     binding.WebViewMy.settings.loadWithOverviewMode;

    binding.WebViewMy.webViewClient

}
//@ovveride
public  boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView WebviewMy,
WebResourceRequest request)
{
    binding.WebViewMy.loadUrl("foo.com");
}

**

Ответ на выше опмисаный вопросс мне адли ниже.
Я исправил, написав код на котлин, а не джава.
Но вот еще ошибку выдает:
Komdosh, я сделал так,, public fun shouldOverrideURLLoading(webView: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean { binding.WebViewMy.loadUrl("foo.com"); return true; } } Но пишет ошибку в браузере (WebView) - ERR_CASHE_MISS и не открывает сайт

Не забывайте про permissions в манифесте же

Это объявление метода на Java:
public boolean shouldOverrideURLLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request)

На kotlin метод объявляется следующим образом:
public fun shouldOverrideURLLoading(webView: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean


Komdosh, я сделал так,,     @Override
public fun shouldOverrideURLLoading(webView: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean
{
binding.WebViewMy.loadUrl("foo.com");
return true;
}
} Но пишет ошибку в браузере (WebView) - ERR_CASHE_MISS и не открывает сайт

и еще вот вы написали как сделать - запускалось без ошибок, а сейчас точно такой же код и ошибка: Modifier 'public' is not applicable to 'local function'

Err_cache_miss не относится к описанной в вопросе проблеме.

‘local function’ это объявление функции внутри другой функции (fun внутри другого fun), там действительно модификаторы доступа недоступны

Как то очень сложно...
Проще так...
Котлин...
Сразу после объявления класса

private lateinit var webView: WebView

после onCreate

setContentView(R.layout.web_view)

webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()



val webSettings = webView.settings

webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true


webView.loadUrl("https://site.com")

Пиши, если нужно больше...
